# css- how to align all textbox?

Tags: html, css

I have a screen that I want to align the textbox so they are all on the same position. Below is the screenshot where it's not aligned:

[image]

My code:

```html
<label>File Name:&emsp;</label>
<input type="text" size="30" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" readonly>
<br><br>
<label>URL Link:&emsp; </label>
<input type="text" size="100" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" readonly>
<br><br>
<label>Start Date:&emsp;</label>
<input class="txtStartDate" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" readonly>
<br><br>
<label>End Date:&emsp; </label>
<input class="txtEndDate" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value="<%=defaultDate%>" readonly required />
<br><br>
<label>Enable:&emsp;&emsp; </label>
<input class="mandatory" type="radio" name="radioEnableStatus" value="1" checked />On &nbsp;
<input class="mandatory" type="radio" name="radioEnableStatus" value="0" /> Off &nbsp;
```

Note: `label` is not being used at the moment.

I am using `&emsp` and obviously can't get them to align together. Been trying to fix this for an hour. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: give a size to the label, via display:inline-block or float ;) (mind the for attribute using the label, so it is linked to its own input .

Comment: How does it look like?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

[CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) is the simplest way to go for forms.

A form is a two dimensional array and grid was design for just this purpose.
Tabular data without the need for tables.

Here is a simple example:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 400px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <label>File Name:</label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" readonly>

  <label>URL Link:</label>
  <input type="url" size="100" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" readonly>

  <label>Start Date:</label>
  <input class="txtStartDate" type="date" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" readonly>

  <label>End Date:</label>
  <input class="txtEndDate" type="date" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value="<%=defaultDate%>" readonly required/>

  <label>Enable:</label>
  <div>
    <input id="on" class="mandatory" type="radio" name="radioEnableStatus" value="1" checked/>
    <label for="on">On</label>
    <input id="off" class="mandatory" type="radio" name="radioEnableStatus" value="0" />
    <label for="off">Off</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried using label and it's css but for URL Link textfield, it seems to move the textbox below the word. I need it to stay next to the word.

Comment: This method should not cause any wrapping. It wil overflow if the fields are too big. I fixed the widths in `grid-template-columns: 100px 400px;` column 1 and column 2. Change these as desired for your needs. (%, fr, or px)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Set width to `<label>`

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label>File Name:</label><input type="text" size="30" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" readonly><br><br>

<label>URL Link:</label><input type="text" size="100" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" readonly><br><br>

<label>Start Date:</label><input class="txtStartDate" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" readonly><br><br>

<label>End Date:</label><input class="txtEndDate" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value="<%=defaultDate%>"  readonly required/><br><br>

<label>Enable:</label>
<input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="1" checked/>On
<input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="0" />Off
```

Method 2: Use `<table>`

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">File Name:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="30" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">URL Link:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="100" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">Start Date:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtStartDate" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">End Date:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtEndDate" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value="<%=defaultDate%>"  readonly required/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">Enable:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="1" checked/>On
      <input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="0" />Off
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



<br><br>
```

Comment: It is usually said that html <table> should not be used for layout purpose, so your 1st method is definitely the best one :)

Comment: I ran your 1st method and although they are aligned but for URL link, the textbox moves to the bottom, is there a way to place it next to the word?

Comment: The easiest way is that reduce the `size` of the URL textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fieldset`

```css
label{
display:inline-block;
width:200px;
margin-right:30px;
text-align:right;
}

fieldset{
border:none;
width:500px;
margin:0px auto;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
<label>File Name:</label><input type="text" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" size="20" readonly>
<label>URL Link:</label><input type="text" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" size="20" readonly>
<label>Start Date:</label><input class="txtStartDate" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" size="20" readonly>
<label>End Date:</label><input class="txtEndDate" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value="<%=defaultDate%>" size="20" readonly>
<label>Enable:</label> <input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="1" checked/>On
<input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="0" />Off 
</fieldset>
```

And with divs

```css
form {min-width:30em}
.labels {float:left; line-height:1.7em; padding-right:.3em}
.inputs {line-height:1.7em}
fieldset{border:none;}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
    <fieldset>
    <div class="labels">
        File Name:<br>
        URL Link::<br>
        Start Date:<br>
        Start Date:<br>
        Enable:<br>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" size="20" readonly><br>
        <input type="text" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" size="20" readonly><br>
        <input class="txtStartDate" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" size="20" readonly><br>
        <input class="txtStartDate" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" size="20" readonly><br>
        <input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="1" checked/>On
<input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="0" />Off 
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by solely using HTML or also by including some CSS Styling Elements. The only HTML method can be executed by using the HTML tables and putting your data in different rows, which will automatically align your textboxes. I am uploading the sample code for the first two fields. You can use similar implementation for the rest.

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <th><label>File Name</label></th>
 <td><input type="text" size="30" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" readonly> </td>
 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th> URL Link </th>
 <td> <input type="text" size="100" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" readonly></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so you are using table?

Comment: @Daredevil yes! So that it automatically solves the alignment problem To adjust the spacing between the fields and boxes, you can add width via HTML styling. It won't affect the alignment of your boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a float property

`<div style="width:100%">
    <div style="width:100%">
        <label style="width:30%">File Name:&emsp;</label>
        <input type="text" size="30" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" readonly style="float:right;height:100%;width:70%">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div style="width:100%">
        <label style="width:30%">URL Link:&emsp;</label>
        <input type="text" size="100" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" readonly style="float:right;height:100%;width:70%">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div style="width:100%">
        <label style="width:30%">Start Date:</label>
        <input class="txtStartDate" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" value="<%=currentDate%>" readonly style="float:right;width:70%">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div style="width:100%">
        <label style="width:30%">End Date:</label>
        <input class="txtEndDate" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value="<%=defaultDate%>" readonly required style="float:right;width:70%"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div style="width:100%">
        <label style="width:30%">Enable:</label> 
        <div style="float :right;width:70%">
            <input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="1" checked/>On &nbsp;
            <input class="mandatory" type="radio"  name="radioEnableStatus" value="0" />Off 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
.box{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    width:100%
 }
 input[type=text]{
    width:350px
 }



<div class="box">
   <label>File Name:&emsp;</label>
   <input type="text" size="30" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" readonly>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="box">
   <label>URL Link:&emsp; </label>
   <input type="text" size="100" name="URL Link" value="<%=url%>" readonly>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="box">
   <label>Start Date:&emsp;</label>
   <input class="txtStartDate" type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="Start Date" 
   value="<%=currentDate%>" readonly>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="box">
   <label>End Date:&emsp; </label>
   <input class="txtEndDate" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" value=" 
   <%=defaultDate%>" readonly required />
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="box">
   <label>Enable:&emsp;&emsp; </label>
   <input class="mandatory" type="radio" name="radioEnableStatus" value="1" checked 
   />On &nbsp;
  <input class="mandatory" type="radio" name="radioEnableStatus" value="0" />Off 
  &nbsp;
</div>
```